# Proof of P=n^2-2+41 for n=1,2,3,... generating prime numbers in R

Tags: r, formula, proof

I am curious to see if there is a nice way in R to prove that the formula
P=n^2-2+41 for n=1,2,3,...
is generating prime numbers (until 40)?

Comment: there is no formula for prime numbers. when n=2, we have 1-2+41 = 40 and 40 is not a prime number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  Check for n=1:  (1^2) - 2 + 41 = 1 + 39 = 40.  Not prime.

If you insist on using R code to check this, here's one way:

```
gen_p <- function(n) n^2 + 39
for(i in 1:40) print(gmp::isprime(gen_p(i)))
```

Let me also add that "*demonstrating* something works for many values of n" is not the same as *proving* it works generally for all values of n.

Comment: Could you please explain me what the result of this illustrates? Thank you very much!

Comment: The first line of code creates a function (named `gen_p`) that outputs a value P for any input value of n.  If `n=1` then `gen_p(n)=40`.  The second line of code loops over values of n=1,2,3,...,40.  For each value of n, we calculate P using `gen_p()` and then we ask whether P is prime.  We use the `isprime()` function from the package `gmp` to check whether P is prime.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now, your answer helped me generate a quite clear image this way :                                                                                               
gen_p <- function(n) n^2 - 2 + 41
for(n in 1:50) {
  curr_n <- gen_p(n)
  is_n_prime <- gmp::isprime(curr_n)
  if (is_n_prime == 2) {
    print(c(n, curr_n, "is prime"))
  } else if (is_n_prime == 1) {
    print(c(n, curr_n, "probably prime"))
  } else { 
    print(c(n, curr_n, "not prime"))
  }
}